# recursive sampling in r

Tags: r, sampling

I´m trying to simulate death over 7 years with the cumulative probability as follows:

```
tab <- data.frame(id=1:1000,char=rnorm(1000,7,4))

cum.prob <- c(0.05,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.12)
```

How can I sample from `tab$id` without replacement in a vectorized fashion according to the cumulative probability in `cum.prob` ? The ids sampled from yr 1 can necessarily not be sampled again in yr 2. Hence the `lapply(cum.prob,function(x) sample(tab$id,x*1000))` will not work. Is it possible to vectorize this?

//M

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way: First get the probability of a given individual's dying in a given year as `probYrDeath`, i.e. `probYrDeath[i] = Prob( individual dies in year i )`, where `i=1,2,...,7`.

```
probYrDeath <- c(diff(c(0,cum.prob)).
```

Now generate a random sample of 1000 "Death Years", with replacement, from the sequence 1:8, according to the probabilities in `probYrDeath`, augmented by the probability of not dying by year 7:

```
set.seed(1) ## for reproducibility
tab$DeathYr <- sample( 8, 1000, replace = TRUE, 
                       prob = c(probYrDeath, 1-sum(probYrDeath)))
```

We interpret "'DeathYr = 8'" as "not dying within 7 years", and extract the subset of `tab` where `DeathYr != 8`:

```
tab_sample <- subset(tab, DeathYr != 8 )
```

You can verify that the cumulative proportions of deaths in each year approximate the values in `cum.prob`:

```
> cumsum(table(tab_sample$DeathYr)/1000)
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7 
0.045 0.071 0.080 0.094 0.105 0.115 0.124
```

Comment: Nice work. Very direct approach. Sidesteps all the complications I was adding.

Comment: Ooh. Way better than mine! I didn't realize you can pass probabilities to sample. And the diff is also groovy! You could set the 8 based on the length(cum.prob) + 1 though.

Comment: Very intuitive. Appreciate it. Thx. //M

Comment: You can also avoid the `c(probYrDeath, 1-sum(probYrDeath))` instead of `probYrDeath` complication by using `probYrDeath <- diff(c(0, cum.prob, 1))` in the earlier line

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
prob.death.per.year<-c(1-cum.prob[length(cum.prob)], cum.prob - c(0, cum.prob[-length(cum.prob)]))
dead.in.years<-as.vector(rmultinom(1, length(tab$id),prob.death.per.year))[-1]
totsamp<-sum(dead.in.years)
data.frame(id=sample(tab$id, totsamp), dead.after=rep(seq_along(dead.in.years), dead.in.years))
```

Depending upon which form you want the result in, you can change the last step.